# Header and footer in Magento 2.2.0

Tags: header, footer, magento2.2.0

I am new to magento 2.I want to use custom header and footer design for my site but don't where to keep that code. I am using blank theme. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Add custom header:**

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Add the header template to:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

**Add custom footer:**

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_footer" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer.phtml">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Add the footer template to:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml

Comment: How to add CSS for the header and footer?